# java program to set Wifi router password

Tags: wifimanager

I want to create a java program in which when we give a string, it should set as the Wifi router password. Please help me. I created a java program to generate random password,i need to set that in wifi router automatically.

Comment: Setting the Wifi password involves modifying OS-level configuration.  The details will vary, depending on whether you're on Linux, Windows, Android, etc...  Q: Does this happen to be an Android question?  If so, look [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/WifiManager.html).  And please be sure to tag "Android" to your question.  And if you need to change the router... you're probably stuck with doing it manually :(

Answer (score 1):

The best way I see this happening is you logging in and changing the password manually, while logging all the network traffic. This is something you can then distill to the bare minimum (probably something like first the login request where you provide the router password and then the change password request).

Once you know which files need to be requested, you can just set up your java program to request these files and voila, you're done. There might be some problems along the way, as some routers use a form of encryption on their normal passwords, and even if it does work, it will only work for the router you are currently working with, but I think this should give you a starting point.

Comment: Usually do which files the wifi is requested.?

Comment: As far as I know, there is no usually about this, each router software has its own web interface with its own requests.